# Accessing $post global on a custom post type archive page

Tags: globals

I have a custom post type called projects, and its archive is at `/projects`, on the archive page I get notices `Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object` every time I try to access the `$post` i.e. `$post->post_name`. Is this intended behaviour? Should I just accept that and always check the availability of `$post` before using it?

```
if (!empty($post)) {
    // Do something with $post
}
```

Comment: You should only use `$post` within [the loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

Comment: What alternatives there are outside the loop?

Comment: You can use `if ( have_posts() ) $post = $wp_query->posts[0];`

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of sense to make use of `$post` outside the loop in a post archive, mainly because it yields the problem of "which post?" There are other functions that can provide more useful information though, such as the current post type and its labels, or the current category/tag/term

Comment: Is this question still current? What is it that you want to achieve on this template?

Answer (score 0):

Put in the following line at the top of archive page :

```
global $post;
```

Thing is you need to access the global $post object before trying to use it.

Comment: It doesn't help in this case.

Comment: Than only thing I can think of, is that you are trying to access it on a page where it was not set. However still you can avoid error message by testing if object exists by using : is_object()

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get array values, so you are getting errors. Try with WP_Query, like:

```
global $post;        
$projects = array(
    'post_type'   => 'projects',
    'orderby'     => 'date',
    'order'       => 'DESC',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);
$projects1= new WP_Query( $projects );          
if ( $projects1->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $projects1->have_posts() ) : 
        $projects1->the_post();
        echo $post->post_name;
    endwhile; 
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably just check if the post exists first to prevent errors:
[using post_exists() WP codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_exists/)